# IRFZ44N is not working properly.its Vgs <1v. So how to make it completely on

Tags: driver

[image]

The driver i have used is IRS2110.

Comment: Are you measuring that Vgs with a voltmeter when the circuit is **static** (input signal is not changing) **or** are you measuring the Vgs with an oscilloscope with a **changing** input signal? I ask because the **bootstrap** part of the circuit only works when the output is switching low/high. That bootstrap circuit then makes the voltage needed to drive with a high Vgs.

Comment: Yeah i have measured it using voltmeter and also seen it using oscilloscope.But Vg=11v and Vs=11v.so Vgs is comming 0v.I think my bootstrap ckt is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you refer to the top-side MOSFET and a possible problem with the boot-strapping circuit not generating enough gate drive to turn it on. For boot-strapping to work effectively you need to toggle the input pins of the IRS2110 at a fairly fast rate. If you are trying to put DC voltage levels on the input, the boot-strapping circuit will fail to operate correctly because it needs a reasonably fast toggle rate probably in the low kHz and above.

Boot-strapping is a diode clamp that generates a peak voltage higher than Vcc: -

[image]

Other than that the circuit detail looks correct apart from me nearly missing the tiny inverter you have on pin 12.

Comment: i have put a delay of 3 sec of my square wave to change the duty cycle of 10%.

Comment: If your switching frequency is too low then changing the duty cycle will have no effect.

Comment: My switching frequency is exactly 50Hz.

Comment: It's probably too low to be effective. Normally switching frequencies for these types of circuits are in the kHz regions. Try switching at a higher rate to prove the point and then maybe see at what frequency it starts to not work. It may be possible to make a fix.

Comment: in Khz range my BLDC motor will not work.my aim is to drive BLDC motor. In higher frequency motor speed can not control.

Comment: Make a dummy load and try running at a higher frequency just to prove the point.

Comment: @PradhanAshutosh - Usually with the BLDC motor you setup the driver to be excited with a high frequency PWM signal. The low frequency (the 50Hz you mentioned) comes into play in how you gate the PWM signal on and off (ie. the signal envelope). Note also that some boosted driver circuits are not suitable for use with BLDC motors if the PWM drive to the half bridge has to be completely shut off at lower frequencies. In this case you need to look for a driver circuit that has its own boot strap driver oscillator and driver not using the type that kicks off the (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) center point of the half bridge. Lacking that there are separate circuits that you can design to produce your boosted gate drive voltage. Then you need a half bridge driver that can accept an external boosted voltage input. Having a separate boost driver circuit can be shared between multiple half bridge drivers. Certainly for a BLDC motor you are looking at having at least three or four half bridge drivers.

Comment: yeah i am happy with your reply. I will use 3 H-bridge ckt,but currently i am trying to drive 1 h-bridge ckt .But problem with boot strapping.i need Vgs >=10v.Can u tell me how to get that voltage.

Comment: You could try a higher value boot-strap capacitor. You could also try simulating the circuit. The devil is in the detail and you are in control of the detail. I might even consider adding a fixed power supply that raised pin 6 of the chip to a 10 volt level above the 12 volts. There are several solutions but your basic problem is, I feel now understood by you.

Comment: 1k ohm gate pulldown resistor? Try with something much larger, especially if running at low frequency.

Comment: instead of taking 1k pull down i have take  120k ,But Vgs is coming 6v ,but i need minimum 10v  .What to do???

Comment: @PradhanAshutosh Well, 6 volts is an improvement - did you try making the bootstrap capacitance bigger?